Oracle APEX Custom Authentication Login Page only Accessed when Run Directly
I set up custom authentication for my APEX app (first time doing so)and it's working, but only if I run the login page manually.
If I run the application normally, I get a browser message that the app requires authentication (See below). What I would expect to happen is for the login screen to appear. Same thing happens if I sign out - it will try to open the home page - but obviously I've signed out so credentials will need to be re-entered, but instead of the login page popping up, I get the weird dialog shown.
enter image description here
Also, here's another fun fact about that dialog: No credentials work - neither the custom ones I've set up nor my APEX/Oracle credentials.
I’ve searched the documentation, tried googling, searched all the shared components for relevant settings, but I’ve found no solution.

Hmm.. I would think that message comes from your webserver (ORDS), not from APEX. It seems your webserver requires basic authentication. No idea how to solve it but it might give you some clues about where to look
